# Why suppress functionality does not work with hopping windows?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

How to make it work?
Example of my code:

```
KStream<String, String> finalStream = source
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
                .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> newValue, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
                .toStream();
```

After I run the code above - output stream is empty. There were no errors/exceptions.
NOTE: With Tumbling Window the code working as expected.
Maybe I simply use it incorrectly?

Comment: Please add background and details to question.

Comment: Added more details. Review please. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, window grace period is 24h. Hence, if you don't change it, `suppress()` won't emit any data before the grace period passed.

You can reduce the grace period via `TimeWindows#grace(Duration)` (cf: https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindows.html#grace-java.time.Duration-)

Btw: you might also want to reduce the store retention time for this case (that is also 24h by default), via:

```java
reduce(..., Materialized.withRetention(Duration))
```